# use variable or textfield to pass as parameter to other textfield in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm doing a report for showing balance sheet
my report is completed, just one thing remains is showing the final amount in words
so for that I used a Java function with `int` parameter which will convert that amount into words.

now my problem is that I have calculated and stored final amount in a `textfield`(say `X`)
and I want to pass this amount to Java function
but I tried out by many ways, but I failed
so my question is that how do I pass variable or one `textfield` to other `textfield` as a parameter?

Suggest some ways or ideas?
I googled for same, tried search on jaspersoft forum also.

Comment: You can look into JasperReport parameters, set this parameter from your code and use it in both your text fields.

Comment: @medopal...i know about parameters..but i think you havnt read my question correctly...i want to pass textfield value(calculated) to other textfield element of report ..so how do i achieve this?